# Fade and translate the "position:absolute" element from top to bottom using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Class "anim" needs to fade in from top to bottom

HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;">
    <img src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_bg.png'); ?>" style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_1-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_2-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_3-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_4-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_5-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_6-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_7-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_8-11.png'); ?>">
    <img class="anim" src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_cover_9-11.png'); ?>">
    <img src="<?= site_url('assets/image/right_bg_mid.png'); ?>" style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.anim {
    display:none;
    width:100%; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:-100px; 
    left:0;
}
```

I would like to work with `show()` and `top:0px` in jquery animation, thanks a lot for helping

Comment: have you considered doing it with css3?

Comment: sure, would you mind provide some suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The CSS way:**

Create a costum animation

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Then, apply to the divs you want to fade

```
.anim {
    display:none;
    width:100%; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:-100px; 
    left:0;

-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
   -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
     -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
        animation: fadein 2s;
}
```

if you want the divs to fade in from top to bottom, you can give each of the divs a unique class name and then create a selector for each of them  with the animation css command (the last five lines in the selector above) . The only thing you change is the argument of the seconds. The top should fade the fastest (suppose 0.2s) and then increase it until the last (all the code here should be in one  cssfile)

**The jQuery way**

Put all the divs in an array and then animate each of the while increasing the delay

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".anim").each(function(index, value) {
        $(value).fadeTo(index * 1000, 1);

    });
});
```

While you can play with the fading time (suppose, add index*2000 instead of 1000)
Make sure opacity is 0 before fading

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21494/)**

Comment: I made a more elegant jQuery code and added a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Css3, you just need to change the className of your element.

```
.beforeAnim {
    opacity: 0;
    width:100%; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:-100px; 
    left:0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.anim {
    opacity: 1;
    width:100%; 
    position:absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left:0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. how about showing each anim element one by one? e.g. first element show, after 100second, show the next one and so on..

Answer (score 0):

for supplment to show one by one :

```
    var show_time = 0;

    function show_ball(ball) {
        ball.addClass('after');
    }

    $(".anim").each(function (index) {
        var ball = $(this);

        setInterval(function () {
            show_ball(ball);
        }, show_time);

        show_time += 500;
    });
```